# how not showing the popup message after ShowDeskBand?

Tags: windows, winapi, com, win32com

My program looks like that:

```
ComPtr<ITrayDeskBand> spTrayDeskBand;
CoInitialize(NULL);
HRESULT hr = spTrayDeskBand.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TrayDeskBand);

hr = spTrayDeskBand->IsDeskBandShown(CLSID_MyDeskBand);
ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && hr == S_FALSE)
  hr = spTrayDeskBand->ShowDeskBand(CLSID_MyDeskBand);
```

after i call the show deskband - i get a popup "do you want the MyDeskband bar toolbar on your taskbar?

i want to prevent this message to appears ... how can i do that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You cannot suppress the dialog. The dialog is there [specifically to avoid programs jamming themselves into the taskbar without permission from the user](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/02/9388941.aspx).

Comment: Okay, let me phrase it more precisely. You cannot suppress the dialog via supported documented APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.  It is not supported behavior.